# Converting time format

Tags: excel

There must be a quick solution for this, but after 30min I gave up and need help.

This is the format of source data

```
0h56m40s    0h57m10s    1h00m40s    1h02m15s    1h02m25s
52m47s  54m25s  54m52s  57m23s  57m43s
49m30s  54m31s  54m34s  56m35s  56m36s
47m45s  48m03s  51m02s  52m23s  53m05s
46m54s  49m29s  50m51s  51m02s  51m03s
46m09s  47m56s  50m16s  51m20s  51m53s
46m55s  47m08s  47m13s  48m16s  50m11s
```

and I need this in time format like `0h56m40s` to `0:56:40`

I tried search/replace, from h to :, m to : and removing s, works for when there's hour, but messes up for when only minutes are there.

Any tips?

Comment: Are those times right-aligned or left-aligned in their cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `0:` if the input string is too short:

```
=(IF(LEN(A1)<7,"0:","") & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h",":"),"m",":"),"s",""))+0
```

The `+0` part converts string to time value (change cell format to `h:mm:ss`). If you prefer to keep it in text format, remove `+0`.

Comment: Perfect! Had to translate in french, since my excel is in french!

=(SI(NBCAR(A1)<7,"0:","") & SUBSTITUE(SUBSTITUE(SUBSTITUE(A1,"h",":"),"m",":"),"s",""))+0